# Stop python code in (Fortran) module error using f2py?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am creating a Python module in Fortran using `f2py`. I would like produce an error (including error message) in the Python program if an error is encountered in the Fortran module. Consider the following example:

Fortran code (test.f):

```
subroutine foo(a,m)

  integer :: m,i
  integer, dimension(m) :: a
  !f2py intent(in) :: m
  !f2py intent(in,out) :: a
  !f2py intent(hide), depend(a) :: m=shape(a)

  do i = 1,m
    if ( a(i) .eq. 0 ) then
      print*, 'ERROR HERE..?'
    end if 
    a(i) = a(i)+1
  end do

end subroutine
```

This very simple program adds `1` to each element of `a`. But should produce an error if `a(i)` equal to zero. The accompanying Python code:

```
import test

print test.foo(np.array([1,2],dtype='uint32'))
print test.foo(np.array([0,2],dtype='uint32'))
```

The output is now:

```
[2 3]
ERROR HERE..?
[1 3]
```

But **I want the Python program to hold on the error**. Please help.

**Answer**

The `stop` command in Fortran does exactly this. Consider the updated Fortran code:

```
subroutine foo(a,m)

  integer :: m,i
  integer, dimension(m) :: a
  !f2py intent(in) :: m
  !f2py intent(in,out) :: a
  !f2py intent(hide), depend(a) :: m=shape(a)

  do i = 1,m
    if ( a(i) .eq. 0 ) then
      print*, 'Error from Fortran'
      stop
    end if 
    a(i) = a(i)+1
  end do

end subroutine
```

The output is now:

```
[2 3]
Error from Fortran
```

I.e. the Python code does not continue after the error.

Comment: Are you trying to raise a Python exception from a Fortran module?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: One way would be to retutn an error code from Fortran, check it in python side, and raise an exception if error occured.

Comment: I agree. This is what I considered. But I think this is not the most elegant solution. Also I guess it is possible, since other Python modules can produce these errors.

Comment: Fortran has no support for raising exceptions.

Comment: As much as I love Fortran, I think that you have to give up a certain sense of elegance using it.  Returning an exit code and checking it is probably your most elegant solution, all things considered.

Comment: Returning an exit code is indeed not too bad. My personal preference is that this reduces the readability of the Python code as it involves an extra `if` statement. I did find some solution (see above)

Comment: This thread on the numpy-dev email list has some solutions for your problem: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-January/039672.html

Answer (score 4):

I've suggested to the `numpy` community to add add an extra f2py "enhancement" (`raise_python_exception`) which makes it possible to define a string variable in Fortran that if non-empty will cause Python to raise an exception once the function returns.

So in Fortran you would write something like:

```
subroutine calc_dq(q, temp, dq, error_mesg)
  !f2py raise_python_exception error_mesg

  real, intent(in) :: q, temp
  real, intent(out) :: dq

  character(len=100), intent(out) :: error_mesg

  if (.not. init_called()) then
     error_mesg = "`init` hasn't been called."
  else
     call q_flux_function(q, temp, dq)
  endif
end subroutine calc_dq
```

And called from Python the content of the `error_mesg` variable is used as the content of the exception:

```
In [2]: calc_dq(1.0, 300.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c0ce0cb9cda1> in <module>()
----> 1 calc_dq(1.0, 300.)

Exception: `init` hasn't been called.
```

I think this is quite a convenient way of raising exceptions from Fortran as it allows the exception message to be easily defined. I have put my [suggestion on github](https://github.com/leifdenby/numpy/commit/6df3a9e37836900c1ffdcf6a044acc0f9f5d1866).

Comment: The value of `error_mesg` is undefined in your example in the other conditional branch.

Answer (score 1):

`f2py` does provide some statements that can be used to raise exceptions.  See details [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/signature-file.html#f2py-statements).

In particular, look at `callstatement` which describes how to add `f2py_success = 0` which will trigger an exception.

I'm not sure this will help you with debugging the internals of the fortran library, but at least it is a start.

Comment: Link nowadays: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/signature-file.html#statements and link recovered from Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140625200426/http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/#statements